# UWP Animation resets to From state

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an animation in UWP app which was working (Production Windows Store app) as intended until Windows Update 1809. Something was changed and now the animation resets to `From` value right after it finished.

Example code:

Animation (rotation):

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FlipTest">
    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="TestRotation"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"
                        From="180"
                        To="10"
                        Duration="0:0:1.40"
                        />
</Storyboard>
```

Animated item:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="18">
        <TextBlock.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection x:Name="TestRotation" RotationY="0" />
        </TextBlock.Projection>
    </TextBlock>
```

Call to start from button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)Resources["FlipTest"];
    sb.Begin();
}
```

**Intended behavior (works on Windows 1803):** 
When you click on the button, the TextBlock rotated **and stays** in this state.

**Behavior on Windows 1809:**
The TextBox reset to `From` (180 deg) value right after the animation finished, but before `Storyboard.Completed` event called.

Interestingly, if I put `To="0"`, it stays in this state. If I put 10, 190 or 360 degrees, it resets. Note, it resets not to the original state (which is 0deg), but to `From` value (180deg).

I also updated `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` to the latest version (6.1.9), but it changes nothing.

Could anyone explain this behavior or tell how to fix it? Am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE (ugly workaround)**

I find out that I can use the following ugly hack:

```
    sb.Completed += (s, ee) =>
    {
        TestRotation.RotationY = 0.01; // ugly hack for Windows Build 1809
    };
```

But it looks terrible not only in code. On the screen you can see the terrible **blink**, because after the animation the item resets and then set again to normal value.

I also noticed that `RotationY` hold the correct value after animation completed, although visually the item rotated. You can see the value is 0 in code (on complete animation) or in `Live Property Explorer`, while visually the item rotated to 180 deg.

Comment: I've reported this question to the relevant team. They're investigating it.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem when building on 1803 and 1809. I have tried other released yet but I'm guessing this is an existing bug that's slipped through the cracks; but I do believe it's a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I believe it's a bug** and associated to the `FillBehavior` of the `Storyboard`.

This is happening for me all the way back to the first Windows 10 Build 10240.  For some reason if the result is != 0 then with `FillBehavior.HoldEnd` the state is reset to the `From` value instead of the `To` value (the value the `Storyboard` ends with).

Without looking at the open source code (which would be best IMO) I have done the following which leads me to this assumption.

Verified your existing code on builds of Windows all the way back to the first release of Windows 10.  Tested both `To = 10` and `To = 0`.  `To = 10` resets to the starting `From` value.  `To = 0` resets to original value.  This you've documented already.

Modified `From` value to be 360 degrees past the `To` value (using random values) so that it performs a full rotation.  It does stop at the `From` value at this point also which looks like the `To` value, which only speaks to say that `Storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd` holds to the `From` value.  I know it's not `Storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop` because this does reset to the initial value before the `Storyboard` everytime (which is what `FillBehavior.Stop` is supposed to do).

I'm assuming this based on the various tests I've done including manually writing the `Storyboard`.

**Assumption:**

If the `Storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd`, and the `Storyboard.To` value is not 0, then it will hold to whatever the `Storyboard.From` value was once it has completed.

If the `Storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop` then it works as expected and returns to whatever state the value was in before the animation.

**Suggested work around:**

Although I see you have a work around by using the `Storyboard.Completed` event, I have also another alternative (although it's still not pleasant) which may be cleaner and remove the flickering; it worked for me.

I have set the `Timelines` with `FillBehavior.Stop` that are affected and then I've set the initial value of the properties they are animating to the `To` value.

Note: In your example your `DoubleAnimation.Duration` is greater than your `Storyboard.Duration`.  This will always cause it to reset to this start value (which in this case is the `From` value) as the `DoubleAnimation` never gets to complete.  Make sure your `Storyboard.Duration` is at least as long as your highest child `Timeline` to prevent flickering and undesired effects.

*I initially assumed this was your problem but after setting the `Storyboard` to match, or better, your issue still exists.  Just know that the difference in durations could result in unwanted results, especially when your `Storyboard` is shorter than your child `Timeline`(s).*

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FlipTest"
            Duration="0:0:1.40">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestRotation"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"
                     From="180"
                     To="10"
                     Duration="0:0:1.40" 
                     FillBehavior="Stop"/>
</Storyboard>


TestRotation.RotationY = 10;
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)Resources["FlipTest"];
sb.Begin();
```

Comment: Great research and great help. You got the bounty! Your workaround works! I need to play a while to figure out what is important. To who may have similar problems, I need to point out 3 key components to make workaround works: 1. Set storyboard duration to the same as in `DoubleAnimation`. 2. Set `FillBehaviour="Stop"` for problematic DoubleAnimation only (I had more than one in the `Storyboard`). 3. Make sure that `RotationY` value of `PlanProjection` is set to the same as `To` value in `DoubleAnimation` (this is important, it will still buggy if it set to `From`).